# Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building an Amazon S3 test project (JSP Web Application) in Eclipse and I am trying to run it.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream,
java.io.File,
java.io.InputStream,
java.util.List,
com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials,
com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest,
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary"
%>
<%
            String SUFFIX = "/";            
            // credentials object identifying user for authentication
            // user must have AWSConnector and AmazonS3FullAccess for 
            // this example to work
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
                    "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");

            // create a client connection based on credentials
            AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);



%>
```

I added the following jar file to : Project > Properties > Java build path > add jars

aws-java-sdk-1.10.11.jar

And added the same jar file to the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.

The project compiles and build fine. But when I run it it gives the following exception:

```
Aug 15, 2015 3:14:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/third] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
    at org.apache.jsp.uploadDebug_jsp._jspService(uploadDebug_jsp.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could not initialize class error referring to this line of code...

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

How do I fix it?